# MouseListener seems to doesn't work on EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent component = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(537, 374));
panel.add(component, BorderLayout.WEST);

component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
           if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            System.out.println("success");
           }
    }
});
```

I want to print message when I double click screen (EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent) on  JPanel I think this code has no error but it doesn't print "success" I hope you help me. Thank you.

Comment: if you remove if statement on `e.getClickCount() == 2` does it work ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: no  it doesn't work even I remove e,getClickCount() == 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the mouse listener to the video surface component:

```
mediaPlayerComponent.videoSurfaceComponent().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("click");
    }
});
```

In some older versions the method is called `getVideoSurface()`.